# What is the most portable way to delete element from multidimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, undefined

What is the most portable way to delete element from multidimensional sparse array in javascript?

Will following  work well if rows can be undefined sometimes?

```
if( content[row] ) {
    delete content[row][col];
}
```

Will this work and will it be better?

```
if( r=content[row] ) {
    delete r[col];
}
```

Comment: I don't get the point of "portable" in this question, that is baric javascript (not interacting with dom). it should work everywhere.

Comment: Ideally... but even with arrays, not everyone follows the standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. `delete` will leave an empty space in the array where the element was, like this:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
delete arr[1];
arr; // [0, undefined, 2, 3]
```

To remove an element from an array without leaving a hole, you should use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
arr.splice(1, 1); // Start deleting at index 1, delete one element
arr; // [0, 2, 3]
```

Both of your examples work just fine — if `content[row]` doesn’t exist, the body of the `if` statement won’t be evaluated.

Comment: I conducted a speed test using the splice method. While it is slower than manually deleting elements, you have the benefit of much simpler code. Edit: Plus it keeps the order.

Answer (score 1):

You not only need to delete the element, but to also adjust the length of the array.

I usually set the index of the last element in the array to the replaced element, delete the last element, and decrement the length. It's quick, but it does not retain the structure of the array.

Here's an excerpt from my GameAPI I'm working on:

a is the array, i is the index

```
removeAt    : function(a, i) {

    //Removes an element in array

    if(!(a.length>i)) return false;

    delete a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length-1];
    delete a[a.length-1];
    a.length--;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: No, I need not adjusting the length. So, I can assign to length?

Comment: Also do I need to check dimensions? Won't delete work if element is already deleted?

Comment: Yep. I'm looking for the article that described the different ways browsers handle manipulating arrays... but it's inconsistent, and I change the length as a precaution. I check the length for optimization.

Comment: Well, I found one example of browser inconsistency when it comes to arrays: http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/push-and-pop/